# How to show percentage when form submit?

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm using JQuery to submit the form, how to display the current percentage of the form ?

```js
/* FORM */
$(document).on('submit','form.FormProgress',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    addLoading();
    var dataForm = $(this).serializeArray();
    var actionForm = $(this).attr('action');
    var targetForm = $(this).attr('data-target');
    type: $(this).attr('method');
    $(this).find(":input").attr("disabled", true);
    $wait = $(this).html('<div class="panel panel-info"><div class="panel-body" align="center"><img src="img/wait.gif"></div></div>');
    $(targetForm).load(actionForm,dataForm);
    clearLoading();
    return false;
});
/* FORM */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pace.js](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/) which automatically watches for page loads and ajax navigation and shows a loader.

Comment: I've tried pace.js, how to apply it when the form submit ?

Comment: It should apply automatically?

Comment: i've edit my question, it's my script. how to implement pace.js ? if i include in my page, it's not show when form submit but show when load page. :)

Comment: now I only use the images for loading and I want to replace it with a percentage.